# Output the Scroll Position on Console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to output the scroll position, but my solution doesn't seem to work as expected. What am I doing wrong ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tempScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    function example() {
        console.log("Scroll from Top: " + tempScrollTop.toString());
    };
});
```

```html
<body>      
    <p>some text</p>
    <!-- there are many <p> elements -->
    <p>some text</p>        
</body>
```

Whenever I scroll upwards or downwards the script does't output on the console.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly you never call the `example()` function so it will never execute. You need to call the `example()` function under the `scroll` event of the element required. Secondly you need to update the value of the `tempScrollTop` variable inside the function. Try this:

```js
$(window).scroll(example);

function example() {
  var tempScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  console.log("Scroll from Top: " + tempScrollTop.toString());
};
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check your **scrollTop** value by Scroll inside the div element to display the number of pixels the content of div is scrolled top

```js
function myFunction() {
    var elmnt = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    var y = elmnt.scrollTop;
    document.getElementById ("demo").innerHTML = "Scrolled Top: " + y + "px";
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
    height: 100px;
    width: 250px;
    overflow: auto;
}

#content {
    height: 800px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<p>Scroll inside the div element to display the number of pixels the content of div is scrolled top</p>

<div id="myDIV" onscroll="myFunction()">
  <div id="content">Scroll inside me!</div>
</div>

<p id="demo"></p>
```